Issues with Low $I^2$ in Multivariate Random-Effects Meta-Analysis of DLNMs
Summary: Hi, using R, I am conducting a multivariate random-effects meta-analysis of DLNMs (distributed lag non-linear model) with a quasi-Poisson link that includes 400 studies (two-stage time series design). The results show a very low $I^2$ value, narrow confidence intervals and correlations of $1.0$ (or close to $1.0$) among the random-effects (co)variance components.
Context & Goal: The goal is to better understand the effect of region-specific environmental predictors (operationalized as its region-specific percentile) on a health count outcome. While there is substantive variability across regions in stage 1 results, the low $I^2$ suggests near homogeneity. I'm uncertain if these results are due to model specification, data properties, or another issue.
Key observations in the meta analysis:

$I^2$ is low at around $1\%$, contrary to expectations given the
variability across regions of Stage 1 results.
Narrow confidence intervals, especially along the lagged space of the
predictor.
Correlations of $1.0$ in the random-effects (co)variance components.
The observed effects of the main predictor on the outcome seem, however, valid and match expectations.

Specific Questions:

What might be causing the low $I^2$ values and narrow confidence
intervals in my meta-analysis, and how can I investigate possible
issues?
Are the perfect correlations in my variance components an issue? If
so, are there adjustments available or further tests necessary?
Is the vast variability in population size something to worry about?

Some additional info:

I reduced stage 1 estimates to make the meta-analysis more efficient, but the problem also occurs with non-reduced analyses.
The issue persists if a fixed-effects meta-analysis is used instead
of a random-effects one. In general, there is little difference in
the estimates of the fixed effects between models.
Adding the region population size as a covariate in a meta-regression
without intercept will result in a substantially higher $I^2$ ($34.3\%$),
has little influence on the functional form of cross-predictions, but
minimizes relative risk estimates to the fraction of several 100k.
I used the dlnm package for stage 1 analyses and the mixmeta package for stage 2 analysis.
I repeated analyses, omitting one county every time, but the $I^2$ would only fluctuate around $0.5$ to $1.5$% (roughly), so I concluded it was no one county that was an influential case.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated :)
Simplyfied R-Code:
    library(dlnm)
    library(mixmeta)
    
    nd_lag <- nd_lag_use
    nk_lag <- nk_lag_use
    klag <- logknots(nd_lag,nk=nk_lag)  
    ktemp <- c(.10, .75, .90)
    dfperyear <- 8
    linkfamily <- quasipoisson()
    
    coefs <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(list_regions), ncol=(length(ktemp)+1)*(nk_lag+2))
    vcovs <- as.list(rep(NA, length(list_regions)))
    names(vcovs) <- rownames(coefs) <- list_regions
    
    coefs_reduced <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(list_regions), ncol=length(ktemp)+1)
    vcovs_reduced <- as.list(rep(NA, length(list_regions)))
    names(vcovs_reduced) <- rownames(coefs_reduced) <- list_regions
   
    
    for(regionID in list_regions){
      
      data_interm <- list_data[[regionID]]  %>% arrange(time)
      
      basis <- crossbasis(data_interm$predictor,
                          argvar=list(knots=ktemp, fun="ns"),
                          arglag=list(knots=klag, fun="ns", intercept=TRUE),
                          lag=nd_lag)
      
      model <- glm(outcome ~  basis  + ns(time, dfperyear*10) + dayofweek + school_holiday,
                   family=linkfamily,
                   data_interm)
      
      model.class <- class(model)
      model.link <- dlnm:::getlink(model,model.class)
      
      crosspredictions <- crosspred(basis,model,cen=.5)
      coefs[regionID, ] <- coef(crosspredictions)
      vcovs[[regionID]] <- vcov(crosspredictions)
      

      reduced_estimates <- crossreduce(basis, model, cen=.50)

      coefs_reduced[regionID, ] <- coef(reduced_estimates)
      vcovs_reduced[[regionID]] <- vcov(reduced_estimates)
    
    }
    
    meta_overall <- mixmeta(coefs_reduced, vcovs_reduced, data=data_county_names, random=~1|regionID)
    meta_overall_popsize <- mixmeta(coefs_reduced~0+population_size, vcovs_reduced, data=data_regions, random=~1|regionID)

    summary(meta_overall)
    summary(meta_overall_popsize)


Summary of the meta-analysis:
Call:  mixmeta(formula = coefs_reduced, S = vcovs_reduced, data = data_regions, random = ~1 | regionID)
Multivariate extended random-effects meta-analysis
Dimension: 4 Estimation method: REML
Fixed-effects coefficients




Estimate
Std. Error
z
Pr(>/z/)
95%ci.lb
95%ci.ub




b1
0.018585485
0.004911009
3.784454
0.0001540466
0.008960085
0.02821089


b2
0.012947727
0.004644143
2.787969
0.0053039641
0.003845373
0.02205008


b3
0.231996511
0.007569497
30.648867
0.0000000000
0.217160569
0.24683245


b4
0.007161077
0.005438742
1.316679
0.1879462389
-0.003498661
0.01782082



Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Random-effects (co)variance components  Formula: ~1 | regionID Structure: General positive-definite




Std. Dev







b1
0.0425
b1
b2
b3


b2
0.0199
1.0000000




b3
0.0254
0.9999999
1



b4
0.0266
1.0000000
1
1.0000000



Multivariate Cochran Q-test for heterogeneity: Q = 1615.5052 (df = 1600), p-value = 0.3878
I-square statistic = 1.0%
401 units, 4 outcomes, 1604 observations, 4 fixed and 10 random-effects parameters



logLik
AIC
BIC




1434.9327
-2841.8653
-2766.5767



Additionally, the correlation-matrix of fixed effects:




b1
b2
b3
b4




b1
1.0000000





b2
0.1314210
1.0000000




b3
0.1151054
0.6351313
1.0000000



b4
0.6254141
0.2040512
0.1494284
1.0000000




Summary of the meta-regression with population-size covariate:
Call:  mixmeta(formula = coefs ~ 0 + population_size, S = vcovs, data = data_county_names, random = ~1 | regionID )
Multivariate extended random-effects meta-regression
Dimension: 4 Estimation method: REML
Fixed-effects coefficients




Estimate
Std. Error
z
Pr(>/z/)
95%ci.lb
95%ci.ub




b1
4.865712e-08
1.116145e-08
4.359389
1.304259e-05
2.678107e-08
7.053317e-08


b2
3.012938e-08
9.759965e-09
3.087037
2.021621e-03
1.100020e-08
4.925856e-08


b3
4.348570e-07
3.033987e-08
14.332858
0.000000e+00
3.753920e-07
4.943221e-07


b4
1.984797e-08
1.151122e-08
1.724228
8.466674e-02
-2.713612e-09
4.240954e-08







Std. Dev







b1
0.0401
b1
b2
b3


b2
0.0182
0.9981128




b3
0.1662
0.3130326
0.3706232



b4
0.0254
0.9975053
0.9913033
0.2452154



Multivariate Cochran Q-test for residual heterogeneity: Q = 2436.4581 (df = 1600), p-value = 0.0000
I-square statistic = 34.3%
401 units, 4 outcomes, 1604 observations, 4 fixed and 10 random-effects parameters



logLik
AIC
BIC




1233.2799
-2438.5598
-2363.2712



Additionally, the correlation-matrix of fixed effects:




b1
b2
b3
b4




b1
1.0000000





b2
0.2234173
1.0000000




b3
0.1766417
0.3838141
1.0000000



b4
0.6803561
0.2502138
0.1218041
1.0000000




Welcome to the site. In your output for the "meta-regression with population-size covariate", you've got z-values, but your estimates and standard errors are listed as 0. Perhaps try using exponential notation for the small values?

Thank you, Rick, for your edits to the question and your recommendation on the reporting. I changed the reported output accordingly. :)
